# Coloring a perl die message

Tags: perl

I want to change the color of a die message in my perl script. I am currently using [Term::ANSIColor](http://search.cpan.org/~rra/ANSIColor-3.00/ANSIColor.pm) to do other color changing in my script. The problem I run into with die messages is once the script dies it cannot reset the color to the terminal default and the terminal prompt is whatever color was last used in my script. In this case it turns it red.

Any idea how I can have the script die but still change the color back?

Here is the code block in question;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
require Term::ANSIColor;
use Term::ANSIColor;

print "Loading configuration file\n";

# Check if the specified configuration file exists, if not die
if (! -e $config_file_path) {
    print color 'red';
    die "$config_file_path not found!\n";
    print color 'reset';
} else {
    print color 'green';
    print "$config_file_path loaded\n";
    print color 'reset';
}
```

**Update**

It works but now I am not able to get rid of the part of the die statment that says what line it happened on.

```
Loading configuration file
/etc/solignis/config.xml not found!
 at discovery.pl line 50.
```

Normally I just add a line break the die function and that eliminates any of the normal error output from die. Any idea why its doing that?

**Update 2**

Based on all of your recommendations, I cobbled this together.

```
print STDERR RED, "$config_file_path not found!";
die RESET, "\n";
```

It seems to work correctly. Using the constants for Term::ANSIColor[1](http://search.cpan.org/~rra/ANSIColor-3.00/ANSIColor.pm) was a perfect thing I needed to simply things.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`die` is printing to STDERR while `print` is going to STDOUT.

```
print STDERR color 'red';
die "$config_file_path not found!\n";
```

Note that ... you just died. Your 'reset' isn't going to be printed

You want to concatenate it onto your `die`:

```
die color 'red' . "$config_file_path not found!" . color 'reset';
```

You can also use the constants:

```
use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);

die RED, "THis is death!", RESET, "\n";
```

**EDIT:** Sorry - And to get rid of the "where it happened" part, concatenate a `\n` to the end:

```
die color 'red' . "$config_file_path not found!" . color 'reset' . "\n";
```

Comment: Got it - sorry, I forgot that's what the `\n` did. All the `color` function does is return a control character that the terminal interprets as a color change, so you're including that character in your string with the concatenations.

Comment: +1 for you, the idea of using the `Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);` was an awesome idea. Thanks

Comment: Correction, your updated solution is perfect. I love how it fits on one line.

Comment: Note you can do the same with the constants - just stick the `\n` on the end (I updated that just now too)

Comment: Yep I figured that out, I never bothered to use concats. so I can really reduce my code by a good amount.

Answer (score 7):

There's a few ways to do this.

Use `Term::ANSIColor`'s `colored` function, which seems to automatically add the ANSI reset sequence at the end:

```
die colored( "$config_file_path not found!\n", 'red' );
```

Use the constants interface from `Term::ANSIColor`:

```
use Term::ANSIColor qw( :constants );
$Term::ANSIColor::AUTORESET = 1;
die RED "$config_file_path not found!\n";
```

or

```
die RED, "$config_file_path not found!\n", RESET;
```

You can also <strike>trap `$SIG{__DIE__}`, or</strike> use an `END` block, with a coderef and reset it after printing its arguments. (These are probably not the greatest ideas, but they would allow you to reset the colors under almost any exit circumstance.)

Comment: `END{ }` block is the best way. **++**

Answer (score 4):

I’m sure an `END{}` block in which you reset the terminal back to its blackness is the cleanest solution. That’s what such things are for.

Do **NOT** screw around with `$SIG{__DIE__}`, or you will be unhappy.  Nobody realizes it gets called even for *trapped* exceptions!!

Comment: Yeah I tried the `$SIG{__DIE__}` even though I have no idea what it does. It did not work for me anyway.

Comment: `END{ }` block is the best way. **++**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__DIE__` handler:

```
$SIG{'__DIE__'} = sub {
    print color 'reset';
};
```

From [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> Due to an implementation glitch, the
>   `$SIG{__DIE__}` hook is called even
>   inside an `eval()`.

Hence, you should probably not use this technique.

Comment: What so every trapped exception is supposed to print  that crud? Ug!

Comment: _[tchrist](http://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist)_: Added a quote about it. Thanks.