# Coloring a confess/carp message

Tags: perl

I have written a script that outputs a lot of messages to the terminal. Some message are informative, others are output from Shell commands, and some are error messages. In order for the user to easily read the output in the terminal I would like to color the error messages in a red color.

This works fine, except for the error messages produced by `Carp::confess`. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;
use Term::ANSIColor;

my_func(1);

sub my_func {
    my ( $val ) = @_;
    if( $val != 0 ) {
        confess color("bold red") 
           . "Unexpected value. Abort." . color("reset");
    }
}
```

The output looks like this (with different line numbers):

[image]

The problem is that the color is reset too early, so the stack trace is not colored. If I omit the `color("reset")` call, the stack trace is also colored, but then the terminal prompt after the program exited and the output of all subsequent commands run in the terminal is in red color.

Is this possible to achieve? I have tried both `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler and `END` blocks but it did not work..

See also [Coloring a perl die message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691570/coloring-a-perl-die-message).

Comment: You should be able to tweak how [Carp::Always::Color::Term](https://metacpan.org/source/DOY/Carp-Always-Color-0.07/lib/Carp/Always/Color/Term.pm) does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this can be done (to a satisfactory level) using a die signal handler. Since a die signal handler will catch much more than calls to `confess` ( see [Override die with END or CORE::GLOBAL::die](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/05/override-die-with-end-or-coreglobaldie/) for more information ), we will check the input argument of the die handler for the given leading ANSI escape sequence. If the input string contains `color("red")` we will assume that we were called by `confess`:

```
local $SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    my ( $msg) = @_;
    my $col_red = color( "bold red" );
    if ( $msg =~ /\Q$col_red\E/ ) {
        $msg =~ s/\s+$//;
        $msg .= (color("reset") . "\n");
    }
    die $msg;
};
```

then, in the program we write

```
confess color("bold red") . "Unexpected value. Abort.";
```

hence omitting the `color("reset")` code.

**Edit:**

An improvement to the above can be obtained. Since the script already have control over each `confess` call, a helper sub routine can be written that localizes the signal handler even more:

```
sub error_exit {
    my ( $msg ) = @_;

    local $SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
        my ( $msg) = @_;
        my $col_red = color( "bold red" );
        if ( $msg =~ /\Q$col_red\E/ ) {
            $msg =~ s/\s+$//;
            die $msg . color("reset") . "\n";
        }
        else {
            die $msg;
        }
    };
    confess color("bold red") . $msg;    
}
```

And then, in the script, replace each `confess` call with an `error_exit` call. For example, for the script in the question:

```
error_exit("Unexpected value. Abort.");
```